# css functions and orders that need space to right action

Tags: css, function

Some css functions such as `calc()` need correct spacing to work.

e.g the following css code does not work correctly

```css
.redrow {
    background: red;
    width: calc(100%-100px);
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="redrow"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The correct version of the previous css code is:

```
.redrow {
    background: red;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

(pay attention to spaces in the `calc` function)

What other css functions are there that need correct spacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) I found the note that states that you actually don't need the spacing for `calc` function itself  but rather for the `-` and `+` symbols. Here is the explanation.

> Note: The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace.
>   The operand of calc(50% -8px) for instance will be parsed as a
>   percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while
>   the operand of calc(50% - 8px) is a percentage followed by a minus
>   sign and a length. Even further, calc(8px + -50%) is treated as a
>   length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage. The * and /
>   operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is
>   allowed, and recommended.

So I assume the same rules apply to other css functions which require mathematical operations ( although calc is the only one of this type). Unfortunately I did not find a place where this is stated explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule (without giving a list), all properties that have multiple values (which aren't comma-seperated) require proper spacing.

Shorthands, for example, don't use comma-seperation and therefore need spacing, as you can see here:

```
background: transparent url('image.jpg') center center no-repeat;
margin: 0 auto;
```

The special thing about calc() is that it wants to be compatible to negative values, and `100%--100px` is, as you can imagine, hard to interpret, while `100% - -100px` is perfectly feasible. There is no other case where this problem occurs, as nothing else allows you to use a calculation.

So while at first glance, you would say that clearly, 0 and auto need a space inbetween while the calc function doesn't necessarily, it's really quite the same principle - seperating individual values.